# Get Rows Where Difference Between Two Date Columns is Minimum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table (this is just a sample):

```
id  User    dateAssigned          dateComment
---|-------|---------------------|---------------------|
1  | Usr1  | 2014-12-02 12:35:00 | 2014-12-03 08:13:00 |
2  | Usr1  | 2014-12-02 12:35:00 | 2014-12-02 13:06:00 |
3  | Usr2  | 2014-12-02 07:47:00 | 2014-12-02 07:47:00 |
4  | Usr2  | 2014-12-02 07:47:00 | 2014-11-25 08:07:00 |
```

How do I write a query in SQL Server 2008 to select for each user the row where difference between 
`dateAssigned` and `dateComment` is minimum? In my example, query should return rows 2 and 3.

Thank you.

Comment: It depends how much "minimum" means for you. 1 hour? 1 second? In a short race 1 second is an extreme difference, while it's almost nothing in an entire life. Try to explain what you really want so no one has to guess what you really want.

Comment: @mordack550 I would assume minimum would be the shortest distance between the two fields for each user...  it's not that complicated...

Comment: @Siyual that's not what the OP is asking since he want more than one row, not only the one with the smallest difference.

Comment: @mordack550 The smallest difference per user...  There are two users, thus, two results.  He even states that in the question: `...select for each user the row where difference between dateAssigned and dateComment is minimum`

Comment: @mordack550, yes I want the smallest difference per user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `CTE`(Common Table Expression) and [`ROW_NUMBER` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT id,  [User], dateAssigned, dateComment,
           rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
                     PARTITION BY [User] 
                     ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(minute, dateAssigned, dateComment)) ASC)
    FROM dbo.Users u
)
SELECT id, [User], dateAssigned, dateComment
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: One slight note - in his example, the fourth record will have a negative distance, but he wants the third record for that set.  You may want to get the `ABS()` of the `DATEDIFF`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Username 
                               ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(second, dateComment, dateAssigned)) ASC) AS datesOrder
  FROM @T ) t
WHERE t.datesOrder = 1
```

Row number is equal to 1 for those records corresponding to the minimum difference. Hence, the where clause in the outer select statement retrieves the records desired.

**EDIT:**

I added the ABS function applied to the date difference, since dateAssigned can also precede dateComment.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, of course row_number + partition by is better and faster

```
select * from #t
outer apply (
  select top 1 id from #t t1
  where t1.usr = #t.usr
  order by abs(datediff(second, dateAssigned, dateComment))
) o
where #t.id = o.id
```